# Create a space environment with no gravity, Box2d or not?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cclayer

I want to create a cclayer with 4-5 flying objects, flying in random directions on screen. I also want those flying objects transparent to each other, which means they can fly through each other.

What I can think of Ways to do:

**With Box2D**

1. Create a box2d world with 0 gravity. and add Polygon static ground around the edges of the screen.
2. Give an initial force to each of the flying objects, let them flying around and reflect on the grounds.

Problems: Objects still rest down after sometime.. Don't know why. Objects collide with each other, don't know how to make them fly through each other.

**Without Box2D**

use CCMove for each objects, detect if they reach edge of the screen, calculate new path for their move..

Can someone point me a direction, which way is easier? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should your object rotate after colliding with edges?

Comment: It is optional. You mean make the box2D shape very small?

Comment: if you have to handle complex collisions - go with box2d. if they are simple - handle them yourself

Comment: You are right. Box2D is for collisions, gravity.. Thanks. If you provide an answer below, I will accept. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to handle complex collisions - go with Box2d. If your collisions are simple - handle them yourself.